# How to access same SwiftData Model Container inside Observable Store

Tags: ios17, swift-data, swift-macro

I am trying to access same model container inside Observable class which i have provided to Scene

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
    }.modelContainer(for: [Product.self]
```

I can access this model inside View as following

```
var products: [Product]
@Query(sort: \Product.name)
```

AND

```
 @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
```

But how can i access same model inside

```
@Observable public class ProductStore{
//how to access same model context  OR
//@Query model inside this class throughs same container
```

}

IN CORE DATA

```
class PersistentStore: ObservableObject {
var context: NSManagedObjectContext { persistentContainer.viewContext }
```

I am wondering how i can do it in @Observable class

> @Observable public class ProductStore{  // get same context as declared in App first launch }

Comment: Dependency injection, you could pass the model container or context to the init of the observable type or pass the model context from the view in each function call.

Comment: What do u mean by each function call ? why not one time inside swiftUI init

Comment: It depends on what suits you best, I don’t know your code so it was just an example.  Anyway, this isn’t much different using Core Data with SwiftUI and a StateObject so you could look for examples doing that as well

Comment: @JoakimDanielson What about instantiate a `ModelContainer` inside `@Observable` object `ProductStore` and set it in the app environment `.modelContainer(productStore.container)` ?!?!

Comment: i noticed multiple ModelContainer cause issues while CRUDT operations.

Comment: @quaternionboy I tried briefly to use two model containers but also ran into some issues and even if it would work I assume it meant that you manually need to keep them in sync.

Comment: inside View, i can use @Environment to get context but how can i get context inside ProductStore ?

Comment: Any updates on this? As @shoji said, ModelContainer causes some major issues. It seems like it creates a new context, which fails with Relationships.

Comment: this could be helpful https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftdata/how-to-use-mvvm-to-separate-swiftdata-from-your-views

Answer (score 0):

I do it like so

```swift
import SwiftData

@MainActor
final class SwiftDataCoordinator: NSObject {
    
    static let shared = SwiftDataCoordinator()
    
    let persistenceContainer: ModelContainer = {
        print(URL.applicationSupportDirectory.path(percentEncoded: false))
        let schema = Schema([
            YourModel.self,
            AnoterModel.self
        ])
        
        let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)

        do {
            return try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
    }()
    
    var modelContext: ModelContext {
        persistenceContainer.mainContext
    }
}
```

Later in your code you can use container to fetch your entities.

```swift
        let predicate = #Predicate<YourModel>{ object in
            object.name == name
        }
        var fetchDescriptor = FetchDescriptor(predicate: predicate)
        fetchDescriptor.fetchLimit = 1
        let items = try SwiftDataCoordinator.shared.modelContext.fetch(fetchDescriptor)
        return items.first
```